# Is there a way to download both csv and pdf files under the same download button for R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have made a simple Shiny App and I want the user to be able to download certain pieces of data. I know how to set up the download button to include csv files, but I am unsure of how to include pdf files under the same button. I don't want to create a new download button just for pdfs. It would be much more convenient to have everything available under one button. The pdf file in this example is a graph from FRED showing Illinois GDP trends. I'm not sure how to include it officially in here. But my code below is what I truly have and as you can see the csv for full_data is working just fine.

As always I appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)


full_data <- tibble(
  State = c("IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN"),
  City = c("Chicago", "Rockford", "Naperville", "Chicago", "Rockford", "Naperville","Fort Wayne", 
           "Indianapolis", "Bloomington", "Fort Wayne", "Indianapolis", "Bloomington"),
  Year = c("2008", "2008", "2008", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2009", "2009", "2009"),
  GDP = c(200, 300, 350, 400, 450, 250, 600, 400, 300, 800, 520, 375)
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "year",
    label = "Year",
    multiple = TRUE,
    choices = unique(full_data$Year),
    selected = unique(full_data$Year)
  ),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "state",
    label = "State",
    choices = unique(full_data$State)
  ),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "dataset",
    label = "Select Data to Download",
    choices = c("Full Data",
                "Illinois Trends")
  ),
  downloadButton(outputId = "downloadData",
                 label = "Download"),
  plotlyOutput("gdp_level", height = 400),
  shinyjs::hidden(actionButton("clear", "Return to State"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "Full Data" = full_data,
           "Illinois Trends" = "Data/illinois_graph.pdf")
  })
  
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  
  drills <- reactiveValues(category = NULL,
                           sub_category = NULL)
  
  
  gdp_reactive <- reactive({
    full_data %>%
      filter(Year %in% input$year) %>%
      filter(State %in% input$state)
  })
  
  
  gdp_reactive_2 <- reactive({
    full_data %>%
      filter(Year %in% input$year) %>%
      filter(State %in% input$state) %>%
      filter(City %in% drills$category)
  })
  
  
  gdp_data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(drills$category)) {
      return(gdp_reactive())
    }
    else {
      return(gdp_reactive_2())
    }
  })
  
  
  output$gdp_level <- renderPlotly({
    if (is.null(drills$category)) {
      plot_title <- paste0("GDP Level of ",  input$state)
    } else {
      plot_title <- paste0("GDP Level of ",  drills$category)
    }
    
    
    gdp_data() %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~ Year,
        y = ~ GDP,
        color = ~ City,
        key = ~ City,
        source = "gdp_level",
        type = "bar"
      ) %>%
      layout(
        barmode = "stack",
        showlegend = T,
        xaxis = list(title = "Year"),
        yaxis = list(title = "GDP"),
        title = plot_title
      )
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "gdp_level"), {
    x <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "gdp_level")$key
    if (is.null(x))
      return(NULL)
    if (is.null(drills$category)) {
      drills$category <- unlist(x)
    }  else {
      drills$sub_category <- NULL
    }
  })
  
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(drills$category)) {
      shinyjs::show("clear")
    }
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(c(input$clear, input$state), {
    drills$category <- NULL
    shinyjs::hide("clear")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the downloadable files in a temporary directory whose contents you then deliver as a zip bundle:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    ## helper functions to create some dummy PDF and CSV:
    store_sample_PDF <- function(file_name){
        pdf(file = file_name); plot(1); dev.off()
    }
    store_sample_CSV <- function(file_name) write.csv(iris, file = file_name)

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        contentType = 'application/zip',
        filename = function() paste0("data-", Sys.Date(), ".zip"),
        content = function(file) {
            ## set name for directory to be zipped:
            bundle_dir_name <- file.path(tempdir(),'bundle')
            ## create fresh zipping directory:
            if(dir.exists(bundle_dir_name)){
                unlink(bundle_dir_name, recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE)
            }
            dir.create(bundle_dir_name)

            ## replace the following with the real code:
            store_sample_PDF(file.path(bundle_dir_name, 'my_pdf.pdf'))
            store_sample_CSV(file.path(bundle_dir_name, 'my_csv.csv'))

            zip::zip(zipfile = file,
                     files = dir(bundle_dir_name, full.names = TRUE),
                     mode = 'cherry-pick'
                     )
        }
    )
}
```

see example [here](https://elter-crocotile.datalabs.ceh.ac.uk/)

Comment: This is definitely a better solution than I have. Any suggestions as to how the user can select from the directory? Something like "if input$dataset ==  "Full Data" select Full Data from zipfile"?

Comment: If I understood you right, in that case you'd create and populate the directory of zip candidates before (i. a. by having the user switch between "Full Data" and other), and reactively update a `checkboxGroupInput` with the available files as options. The checked values could then be fed to the `zip(..., files = ...)` argument (file list implemented as a reactive value again).